# Error spring mvc y tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

estoy tratando de aprender java con spring mvc en eclipse neon, con tomcat 8.

tengo este unico controlador por ahora:

```
package com.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("indicaciones")
public class IndicacionesController {

    @Autowired
    @RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getPage() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("hello");
        return view;
    }
}
```

tengo una vista llamada hello.jsp dentro de una carpeta llamada views. Mi proyecto se llama "Indicaciones" y cuando quiero acceder a la url: http://localhost:8080/Indicaciones/ me sale error 404.
Ademas de eso en la consola de servidor me sale una excepcion al deployar:

> GRAVE: Error configurando escuchador de aplicación de clase
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.indicaciones</groupId>
  <artifactId>Indicaciones</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Indicaciones Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.2.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
     </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Indicaciones</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

alguna idea de como solucionar esto y poder acceder a la url de mi aplicacion?

Comment: Si tu proyecto se llama Indicaciones, es posible que la url que necesites sea http://localhost:8080/Indicaciones/indicaciones/page, por tu request mapping

Comment: tampoco funciona

Comment: Usas maven? ¿Qué dependencias tienes añadidas?

Comment: si uso maven, arriba puse mis dependencias

Comment: En mi caso, lo que me funcionó fué eliminar el módulo web en la pestaña "Modules" del servidor (Tomcat 9) y volverlo a añadir

Answer (score 1):

Revisando en el sitio en inglés hallé [algo similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl).

Podrías intentar lo que sugieren:

Agregar las dependencias de maven en el ensamblaje del despliegue web del proyecto.

1. Abre las propiedades del proyecto (es decir, ., haz click derecho sobre el nombre del proyecto en el explorador de proyectos y selecciona "Properties").
2. Selecciona "Deployment Assembly".
3. Dale click en el botón "Add..." que está en el margen derecho.
4. Selecciona "Java Build Path Entries" desde el menú de Directive Type y dale click en "Next".
5. Selecciona "Maven Dependencies" desde el menú Java Build Path Entries y dale click en "Finish".

Deberías de ver ena entrada llamada "Maven Dependencies" agregada a la definicióndel Web Deployment Assembly.